# Subversion bidirectional commit and sync

Tags: svn, synchronization

i have a subversion 1.6, it has one repo and mirrored repo. The mirrored repo is read only ofcourse. is there a way to commit and sync between these repos in both directions ?

Comment: ...maybe I'm missing something, but if one of them is read-only why would you need bidirectional sync - surely the read-only one won't ever have any changes to distribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.wandisco.com/subversion/replication?  They do a whole line of products related to multi-site SVN, but they cost.  Never tried them, myself, but that's where I ended up when I last looked for this.

You are going to get into a whole heap of problems trying to do it manually but, the closest I got was:

1. Maintain a list of 'partner' SVN repositories at each site
2. Add pre-commit hooks to both repos to 'lock' the other repos in the partner list:

   1. check for the existence of a semaphore file, bail if it exists
   2. create the semaphore file on each partner server
3. Add post-commit hooks to both repos:

   1. check out the latest revision in a temporary folder working copy
   2. `svn switch --relocate` the working copy to each partner
   3. commit at the relocated repo
   4. remove the semaphore file
4. Periodically verify each repo by using `md5sum` against an `svnadmin dump`

   1. Pick one to clobber the others, in the event of a checksum mismatch
   2. Take copious backups of all partners, in case someone complains about the clobber and you need a revision back

I'll save you the effort -- it didn't work very well.  An absolute mare to setup and fraught with race conditions (you just cannot synchronise the semaphore file fast enough).

Comment: got to go on dvcs

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer:** No

**Longer answer:** you can use "svnadmin dump-transfer dump- delete repo -recreate repo - svnadmin load" path, but it's nightmare

PS: DVCS seems as more natural solution in your case

Comment: +1 - it is a nightmare

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: **yes**.

You can use VisualSVN Server's [Multisite Repository Replication feature](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/multisite-replication/) which allows bidirectional data replication between multiple repositories. The feature is based on VisualSVN Distributed File System technology which **allows your slave repositories be writeable**.